The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLED.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"
I have Microsoft access connection engine 2016 64 bit installed on my machine but when trying to load my access Database to my VB I am getting an error " "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLED.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine". What could be the reason?
I tried changing CPU type in Vb to anu CPU and the selected ARM64, tried installing a 32 bit version so that I can force VB to work on the 32 bit one Microsoft does not allow me to install 32 bit to a 64 bit machine. The connection string I am using is: Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Cricket.accdb"

Do you have Prefer 32-bit checked in the application's Build configuration?

Hi thank you for your response I had ARM64 selected in VB instead of x64. It took me a while to figure it out
